# Is spurious regression impossible if you include lagged error terms?

Tags: time-series, spurious-correlation

If you have a random walk A, and a random walk B, and you regress them against each other you run into spurious regression.

In our textbook however is written that it is impossible to have spurious regression in dynamic models.

So in case you regress A against lagged terms of A plus B and lagged terms of B, you don't have the problem of spurious regression?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not clear what is meant with spurious regression. It is not clear how the regression in the last paragraph is supposed to take place and under what circumstances it is interpreted as 'spurious'. In addition there is a reference to 'in our textbook' but the textbook or background are not given.